# PUT: command not found using elasticsearch

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

i am new to ElasticSearch and i am following the guide on its official website.
when i tried shorthand syntax given in the guide i.e.

```
PUT /megacorp/employee/1
{
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" :  "Smith",
    "age" :        25,
    "about" :      "I love to go rock climbing",
    "interests": [ "sports", "music" ]
}
```

my terminal gives this error

> PUT: command not found

please guide me what trick i am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PUT is not a command, you need to use something like curl, try this:

```
curl -PUT http://localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/1 -d '
{
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" :  "Smith",
    "age" :        25,
    "about" :      "I love to go rock climbing",
    "interests": [ "sports", "music" ]
}'
```

- http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html
- http://www.elasticsearchtutorial.com/elasticsearch-in-5-minutes.html

Comment: it works fine but as mentioned in the official guide that we can use shorthand format like **PUT /megacorp/employee/1** instead of the whole statement with curl, that does not work for me